# Loop over SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure In which  insert query fire on two table.
`masters_table,child_table` as you see here `@Value1,@Value2,@Value3,@Value4` having parameter. I have written insert statement for each block, can I make use loop here to avoid multiple insert write for each block, suppose I have nth value then i have to write nth time block wise insert query, any better way to achieve this task

```
Create proc sp_insert_master_child
    (
     @Details_Data custom_tb READONLY,
     @Value1 nvarchar(500),
     @Value2 nvarchar(500),
     @Value3 nvarchar(500),
     @Value4 nvarchar(500),
     @Value5 nvarchar(500),
     @Value6 nvarchar(500),
     @Value7 nvarchar(500)
    )
as begin 
    declare @id bigint 

    ------- block 1
    if @Value1 is not null
    begin
    insert into masters_table (col1,col2,col3))
    select  Substring(@Value1, 1,Charindex(',', @Value1)-1) as col_value_1,
    Substring(@Value1, Charindex(',', @Value1)+1, LEN(@Value1)) as  col_value_2
    select @id = @@IDENTITY

    insert into child_table (col1,col2,col3)
     SELECT @id,col_val_2,col_val_3 FROM @Details_Data WHERE blockType='blk_1';
     end

    ------ block 2
    if @Value2 is not null
     begin
    insert into masters_table (col1,col2,col3))
    select  Substring(@Value2, 1,Charindex(',', @Value2)-1) as col_value_1,
    Substring(@Value2, Charindex(',', @Value2)+1, LEN(@Value2)) as  col_value_2
    select @id = @@IDENTITY

    insert into child_table (col1,col2,col3)
     SELECT @id,col_val_2,col_val_3 FROM @Details_Data WHERE blockType='blk_2';
     end

    ------ block 3

    if @Value3 is not null
     begin
    insert into masters_table (col1,col2,col3))
    select  Substring(@Value3, 1,Charindex(',', @Value3)-1) as col_value_1,
    Substring(@Value3, Charindex(',', @Value2)+1, LEN(@Value3)) as  col_value_2
    select @id = @@IDENTITY

    insert into child_table (col1,col2,col3)
     SELECT @id,col_val_2,col_val_3 FROM @Details_Data WHERE blockType='blk_3';
     end

 ------ block 4

    .......


 ------ block 5

    .......
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

You can insert all parameters into a table .Use while loop and read one by one row (parameter) from table .

Ex:

```
declare @x int

set @x= 1

declare @tmp table ( val int )

while (@x < noofrows)
begin
 ***********
 Use Top @x value to get row(parameter in your case) from table
perform your operation 
*************
increment x(set @X=@x+1)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but i have a problem how i set my where condition

Comment: Did you mean while condition? will you specify clearly?